# Why wrap a C++ library via a C interface using SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, c, wrapper, swig

SWIG novice exploring the feasibility of wrapping a large C++ library primarily for Python access.  Speaking with the developers working on the C++ one has proposed writing a C interop layer that is then wrapped in SWIG.

The two potential options are:

```
   Base|  Interop  | Scripting Access
```

============================================

```
1) C++ |    SWIG   | Supported Languages

2) C++ | C | SWIG  | Supported Languages.
```

Does #2 add some functionality or stability that I am missing?  It looks like a layer of added complexity.  Can anyone suggest why a C layer might be the better interface for wrapping in SWIG?  (In general terms as you haven't seen the library, etc.)

Comment: Keep mind that a one to one mapping of interfaces between different languages is not possible - e.g., passing arrays is solved differently in C, (idiomatic) C++ and Python. The limited Interfacing capabilities of C reduces the chance of problems there. The cost is that the dumbing down of the interface is pushed into the wrapper layer. An alternative would, designing a C++ interface without bells whistles (such as multiple virtual inheritances or overloaded operators). Furthermore, if you have pure C Interface you can also load it as Lib in Python directly,

Comment: @Dietrich Thanks for the info and that is completely inline with what I have seen in the SWIG docs section 'comments on wrapping c++'.  If I understand correctly - if the complexity of the C++ is 'low' enough, a direct interface is no problem?  Totally agree re: the C lib.  I use this via Cython extensively.

Comment: Exactly, a "simple" or portable enough C++ interface shouldn't be a problem. I personally prefer a C++ over a C interface, because there native methods to wrap e.g. ``std::vector<>`` to Python. I have to admit, I never looked into how well it works with other languages.

Answer (score 2):

SWIG is very powerful and will eliminate a lot of the laborious boilerplate code that you would have to write otherwise. Even with boost::python there is such boilerplate code, although far less than doing everything from scratch. The nice thing with SWIG is that it also makes it easy to integrate with additional languages. For instance I had a C++ library that I was exposing to C# so I could build the GUI in C#/WPF, and with the same SWIG input files, exposed to Lua so that the GUI could be scripted via the C++ layer. It was awesome!

About the C layer of your #2 option, I don't see the benefit, except if you want to integrate with a language that doesn't support C++, but I am not aware of such language (SWIG supports about 20 and I only know 4 so maybe one of the others has such restriction). SWIG is very capable, and can in fact wrap rather complex interfaces. With SWIG you can completely change the API if you wish using the %inline and %extend directives. I can't think of a reason that a C layer would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc) which works with C++ directly.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Access for a range of scripting languages is a goal of this exploration - Python being the primary focus, but PHP access is also important.  I'll take a peak at boost python.